# Use Twisted's getPage as urlopen?

Tags: python, django, twisted, urllib2, urllib

I would like to use **Twisted non-blocking getPage** method within a webapp, but it feels quite complicated to use such function compared to urlopen.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achive:

```
def web_request(request):
   response = urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.org')
   return HttpResponse(len(response.read()))
```

---

**Is it so hard to have something similar with getPage?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The thing to realize about non-blocking operations (which you seem to explicitly want) is that you can't really write sequential code with them. The operations don't block because they don't wait for a result. They start the operation and return control to your function. So, `getPage` doesn't return a file-like object you can read from like `urllib.urlopen` does. And even if it did, you couldn't read from it until the data was available (or it would block.) And so you can't call `len()` on it, since that needs to read all the data first (which would block.)

The way to deal with non-blocking operations in Twisted is through `Deferreds`, which are objects for managing callbacks. `getPage` returns a `Deferred`, which means "you will get this result later". You can't do anything with the result until you get it, so you add *callbacks* to the `Deferred`, and the `Deferred` will call these callbacks when the result *is* available. That callback can then do what you want it to:

```
def web_request(request)
    def callback(data):
        HttpResponse(len(data))
    d = getPage("http://www.example.org")
    d.addCallback(callback)
    return d
```

An additional problem with your example is that your `web_request` function itself is blocking. What do you want to do while you wait for the result of `getPage` to become available? Do something else within `web_request`, or just wait? Or do you want to turn `web_request` itself non-blocking? If so, how do you want to produce the result? (The obvious choice in Twisted is to return another `Deferred` -- or even the same one as `getPage` returns, as in the example above. This may not always be appropriate if you're writing code in another framework, though.)

There *is* a way to write sequential code using `Deferreds`, although it's somewhat restrictive, harder to debug, and core Twisted people cry when you use it: `twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks`. It uses the new generator feature in Python 2.5 where you can send data into a generator, and the code would look somewhat like this:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def web_request(request)
    data = yield getPage("http://www.example.org")
    HttpResponse(len(data))
```

Like the example that explicitly returned the `d` Deferred, this'll only work if the caller expects `web_request` to be non-blocking -- the `defer.inlineCallbacks` decorator turns the generator into a function that returns a `Deferred`.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for the awesome reply!! :D Unfortunately the first example is returning Deferred object instead of the HttpResponse object!!

Comment: Your code didn't return the HttpResponse object either, but yes, this comes down to what I explained about the caller expecting `web_request` to be blocking. You can't change something from blocking to non-blocking without changing how it's called.

Comment: I'm saying it's *far* from simple.

Comment: @Thomas: what if I use a while loop with a timeout in there? :|

Comment: RadiantHex, you're going to have to accept that if you want non-blocking operations you can't use blocking code.

Comment: If you use a while loop, it's blocking again. Why would you want to use `getPage` in order to have a non-blocking operation just to make it blocking again?

Answer (score 4):

I [posted a response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671780/twisted-python-getpage/2671812#2671812) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671780/twisted-python-getpage) recently that provides the minimal amount of code required to get the contents from a URL using `getPage`.  Here it is for completeness:

```
from twisted.web.client import getPage
from twisted.internet import reactor

url = 'http://aol.com'

def print_and_stop(output):
    print output
    if reactor.running:
       reactor.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'fetching', url
    d = getPage(url)
    d.addCallback(print_and_stop)
    reactor.run()
```

Keep in mind that you'll probably need a more in-depth understanding of the [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) used by Twisted to handle events (`getPage` firing being an event in this instance).